# Is there a dumb "all" in linq that evaluate all element?

Tags: c#, linq

Just like operator "&" will execute second condition even if first one is false,
I'm looking for the same thing for "All". I want the result of "All" but also want each elements to be evaluated. I called that a dumbAll in my example.

Here is an example of why I want this.

```
main
{
   Object[] array = InitSomeArray();
   AreObjectValid = array.dumbAll(o => Validate(o));
   //other stuff with AreObjectValid 
}

private bool Validate(object o)
{
    bool IsValid = IsPositiveNumeric(o.ToString());
    HighLighInvalidObjectWhenInvalid(o, IsInvalid: !IsValid);
    return IsValid;   
}
```

**Does such thing exists in linq?**
Note : I already know how to handle this without link.

Comment: Sounds like you want a foreach loop rather than an `All`

Comment: @Asas Shh, LINQ is the future.

Comment: The fact that you need to do this, meaning that the validation is causing side effects, is a pretty big red flag that something very wrong is going on here.

Comment: I'd be wary of using Linq for side-effects. Must Linq methods are lazily evaluated, so you might actually find the function not getting called at all (or multiple times), depending on how you use the result. Just use a foreach loop. It'll make the intention of the code much more obvious.

Comment: Well, seeing the answers, I've got to aggree with you @Pieter Witvoet. I will probably go that way. The answer is clearly no, there isn't such thing. Both Jeff and Marius have come with good work around.

Comment: In the end, removed method "HighLigh" from method "Validate". This allowed me to remove parameter "IsInvalid" in "HighLigh" method. I than did, foreach(var obj in array.Where(o=Validate(o))) HighLigh(obj);        It's seem it doesn't exists for a reason. To prevent doing bad stuff like I was about to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really, but you can achieve this aggregating the results.

```
var allValid = array.Aggregate(true, (acc, o) => acc & Validate(o));
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it :D (...and I got it wrong...)

Answer (score 5):

You can use other query operators to achieve the same. One example is to count how many objects satisfy the condition.

```
Object[] array = InitSomeArray();
var count = array.Count(o => Validate(o));
var areObjectsValid = count == array.Length;
```

Answer (score 2):

I like this less than the `Aggregate` answer (and the `Count` answer as long as you have an array), but here:

```
AreObjectValid = array.Select(o => Validate(o)).ToArray().All(b => b);
```

or, as [Asad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1726343/asad) points out,

```
AreObjectValid = array.Select(Validate).ToArray().All(b => b);
```

Comment: You don't need to create a lambda here. `Validate` can be passed as a method group.

Comment: @Asad Cheers, that's one advantage this has over the Aggregate version.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bunch of LINQ answers here, but because I believe LINQ transformations should ideally be side effect free, here's an approach that uses a `foreach` and doesn't really sacrifice too much conciseness.

```
bool all = true;
foreach(var o in array) 
    all &= Validate(o);
```

This evaluates `Validate` for each value, and at the end `all` will be false if any of the values failed validation.